# get error :cannot commit a resource enlisted in a global transaction in activemq

Tags: activemq-classic, apache-camel, distributed-transactions, bitronix

Could you please help to solve the problem with XA transactions on Activemq and Oracle and Bitronix.
I have a activemq and using camel.xml embeded in for routing message from one queue to oracle db. 
this is the content of camel.xml file in conf folder of standalone Activemq.

```
<camelContext id="camel" xmlns="http://camel.apache.org/schema/spring">

       <route id="partnerToDB">
            <from uri="activemqXa:example.A" />
             <transacted ref="PROPAGATION_REQUIRED"/>
            <transform>
                <simple>insert into tbl_1(body,type) values('${in.body}','P')  </simple>
            </transform>
            <to uri="jdbc:dataSource" />                
       </route>   


</camelContext>


 <!-- TX configuration -->

<bean id="jtaTransactionManager" class="org.springframework.transaction.jta.JtaTransactionManager">
    <property name="transactionManager" ref="transactionManager"/>
    <property name="userTransaction" ref="transactionManager" />
</bean>

<bean id="btmConfig" factory-method="getConfiguration" class="bitronix.tm.TransactionManagerServices">
    <property name="serverId" value="spring-btm" />
</bean>

<bean id="transactionManager" factory-method="getTransactionManager" class="bitronix.tm.TransactionManagerServices" depends-on="btmConfig" destroy-method="shutdown" />

<bean id="PROPAGATION_REQUIRED" class="org.apache.camel.spring.spi.SpringTransactionPolicy">
    <property name="transactionManager" ref="jtaTransactionManager"/>
    <property name="propagationBehaviorName" value="PROPAGATION_REQUIRED"/>
</bean>

<!-- JMS configuration -->

<bean id="resourceManager" class="org.apache.activemq.pool.ActiveMQResourceManager" init-method="recoverResource">
    <property name="transactionManager" ref="transactionManager" />
    <property name="connectionFactory" ref="pooledJmsXaConnectionFactory" />
     <property name="resourceName" value="activemq.default,java/testDS1" />
</bean> 

<bean id="pooledJmsXaConnectionFactory" class="bitronix.tm.resource.jms.PoolingConnectionFactory" init-method="init" destroy-method="close" >
    <property name="className" value="org.apache.activemq.ActiveMQXAConnectionFactory" />
    <property name="uniqueName" value="activemq" />
    <property name="maxPoolSize" value="8" />
    <property name="driverProperties">
        <props>
            <prop key="brokerURL">tcp://172.16.9.17:61617</prop>
        </props>
    </property>
</bean>

<bean id="activemqXa" class="org.apache.activemq.camel.component.ActiveMQComponent">
    <!-- because of https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/AMQ-3251, we cannot use the XaPooledConnectionFactory in AMQ 5.5.1 -->
    <property name="connectionFactory" ref="pooledJmsXaConnectionFactory"/>
    <property name="transacted" value="false"/>
    <property name="transactionManager" ref="jtaTransactionManager"/>
</bean>


<!-- JDBC configuration -->

<bean id="dataSource" class="bitronix.tm.resource.jdbc.PoolingDataSource"
    init-method="init" destroy-method="close">
    <property name="className" value="bitronix.tm.resource.jdbc.lrc.LrcXADataSource" />
    <property name="uniqueName" value="java/testDS1" />
    <property name="maxPoolSize" value="5" />
    <property name="minPoolSize" value="0" />
    <property name="allowLocalTransactions" value="false" />
    <property name="testQuery" value="SELECT 1 FROM DUAL" />
    <property name="driverProperties">
        <props>
            <prop key="user">test</prop>
            <prop key="password">test</prop>
            <prop key="url">jdbc:oracle:thin:@db1sh:1521/org.amin.org</prop>
            <prop key="driverClassName">oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver</prop>
        </props>
    </property>
</bean>
```

when I run Activemq and send a message to example.A queue, nothing is inserted on db and message is dequeued from queue, I get this error in activemq log: 
[org.apache.camel.RuntimeCamelException - java.sql.SQLException: cannot commit a resource
 enlisted in a global transaction]

---

Also I have run these SQL scripts for Oracle DataBase:

```
$ORACLE_HOME/javavm/install/initxa.sql

$ORACLE_HOME/javavm/install/initjvm.sql
```

and the following grant statments:

```
 grant select on pending_trans$ to public;

 grant select on dba_2pc_pending to public;

 grant select on dba_pending_transactions to public;

 grant execute on dbms_system to <user>;
```

Any ideas/solutions are welcome!
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looking at the first lines in the [camel jdbc component docs](http://camel.apache.org/jdbc) I find this information box

> This component can not be used as a Transactional Client. If you need transaction support in your route, you should use the SQL component instead.

Comment: Thanks petter for your quick and accurate respond.

Comment: I changed jdbc and use sql. Now I don't have previous error, but If the insert command can not run on oracle and get error,the message is dequeued from example.A queue. something like that there is not any transaction. Can you help me for this problem?